# Install latest libboost and libraries in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, boost

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with libboost1.65-dev. Thankfully, I am able to upgrade libboost (to version 1.69 or 1.70) using PPAs. However, these PPAs do not come with latest boost libraries such as chrono, atomic, math, etc. How do I install libboost1.69 along with libboost-math1.69  and other boost libraries in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I tried mhier/libboost-latest and boost-latest/ppa (outdated).

Comment: Of course, installing from source is an option. But I am actively trying to avoid that.

Comment: The `libboost-latest` PPA has libboost1.74.

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the source:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr && ./b2 stage threading=multi link=shared
```

Now, as the root user:

```
./b2 install threading=multi link=shared && ln -svf detail/sha1.hpp /usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp
```

Instructions can be found from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/boost.html).